# How can I solve a two variable equation for it to depend on one variable with SymPy?

Tags: python, math, sympy

I've been trying to make an optimization calculator for a project. I'm doing a basic example with the area of a square. To get an equation that I need to derivate I must solve P=XY so the expression I want it to display is Y =P/X.
I'm planning on it to be more accesible than just allowing integers as input, so I'm trying the solver methods like this:

```
from sympy import *
x, y, p = symbols('x y z')
AExp = x*y
print(solve((x*y),p))
```

But I get the error

```
ValueError:
Since there is more than one variable in the expression, the
variable(s) of differentiation must be supplied to differentiate
```

Other solvers appear to be used for more complicated expressions so I'm at doubt on if I should use them and how.

Comment: which version of python are you using? You code in `python 3.6.7`, gives `[]` as output.

Comment: Python 3.7
Some do return me empty lists, like ```Solveset()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the error message, but the code from the question has some issues:

- `x, y, p = symbols('x y z')` creates `x` and `y` which are printed as 'x' and 'y' and `p` which will be printed as 'z'
- `AExp = x*y`: creates an expression being the product of `x` and `y`
- `solve((x*y),p)`: tries to find a `p` for the equation `x*y = 0`

Here is some code to find a `y` such that `p = x*y` :

```py
from sympy import *
x, y, p = symbols('x y p', real=True) # telling sympy which type of solutions to search for helps prevent misunderstandings
my_expr = x*y
my_eq = Eq(my_expr, p)   # equation x*y = p
print(solve(my_eq, y))   # find a y for the equation
print(solve(Eq(x*y, p), y))   # shorthand for the same
```

This outputs: `[p/x]`